# Why does Chabad not "do" conversions?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, chabad

Lubavitch institutions do not conduct conversions. I read somewhere that it is because of some agreement between the Lubavitcher Rebbe and Rabbi Moshe Feinstein.

Why does Chabad not "do" conversions?

Comment: Should you be interested, please put it in Google Translate: http://zsido.com/harom-beterovel-zarult-a-gijur-tanfolyam/

Comment: @ezra There are Chabad rabbonim who do conversions. I could give you a handful of names. Since it seems it's a sensitive issue, I won't post them here, though. As for why they do them, while other Chabad seem not to, I'm not sure.

Comment: @SAH I believe it only started later when prejudice against Chabad forced Shluchim to reconsider who they send potential geirim to.

Comment: @YeruchamDavidbenMordecai please don't be sorry - it is just that the fact one Chabad rabbi sits on a non-Chabad beit din is not really a proof that Chabad does conversions. The question is a bit confusing because it doesn't distinguish between Chabad rabbani and batei dinim, but I think the OP meant to ask why there is no Chabad beit din that does conversions

Comment: My Rabbi is CHABAD, and also sits on the Beit Din, in Amsterdam, that decide on conversions.

Answer (score 4):

A Chabad rabbi is not necessarily a Rav. Most who are running Chabad houses are not. Additionally, they understand that to be fair to the people who want to convert they should ideally do so with a beis din that will universally accept that geirus including in Israel without any religious politics getting in the way. It should be noted while a Chabad Rabbi might not be in the converting beis din he might be the sponsoring Rabbi that helps the person reach out to the people who will be in charge of the conversion.

Comment: According to the OP, there is some sort of policy to **not** do conversions. Your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: "A chabad rabbi is not necesarily a rav" - But many of them are, yet they don't either do convertsions

Comment: there have been chabad ravs that have been on a conversion beis din. This answers addresses the majority of cases which are about shluchim, chabad rabbis at chabad houses

Comment: "A chabad rabbi is not necesarily a rav." Could you please clarify this? "Rabbi" and "rav" are afaik the same word in different languages.

Comment: depending on the type of semicha a person has they will or will not be sought out in making halachic decisions. Perhaps not a linguistic difference in those words but a difference in how they are often practically used.